# Tensor is not an element of this graph - two models used in one project

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using two models in my project. I'm instancing them this way:

models.py:

```
import keras

def CNN_answer_from_model():
    return keras.models.load_model('./KerasModels/CNN_answer.h5')

def CNN_student_index_from_model():
    return keras.models.load_model('./KerasModels/CNN_student_index.h5')
```

DNNApi.py:

```
import Src.Net.model as model
import tensorflow as tf

class DNNApi:

    def __init__(self):
        self.CNN_student_index_model = model.CNN_student_index_from_model()
        self.CNN_answer_model = model.CNN_answer_from_model()

    def evaluate_index(self, img):
        required_height = 290
        required_width = 60

        for img_index_column in get_index_column(img, required_height, required_width):
            self.CNN_student_index_model._make_predict_function()
            graph = tf.get_default_graph()
            with graph.as_default():
                value = self.CNN_student_index_model.predict(img_index_column)
        ...

    def evaluate_answers(self, img):
        # iterate over all AnswerContainer class objects
        for answer_container, img in get_answer_row(img):
            self.CNN_answer_model._make_predict_function()
            graph = tf.get_default_graph()
            with graph.as_default():
               predict = self.CNN_answer_model.predict(img)
        ...
```

What I'm doing is first evaluating *student index from image*, then *answers*.

Evaluating *index* is fine, whole function executes correctly, but then calling `evaluate_answers`, exactly in line `self.CNN_answer_model._make_predict_function()` fails with this error:

```
Tensor Tensor("activation_11/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I have tried all solutions I've found, but they are not saying almost anything about the reason, it's mostly *I did this [...], it helped*, that's why I have *default graph* and make predict function calls. It didn't help me.

In a previous version, I created models every time I evaluated anything, it worked fine, but very slow and memory draining, that's why I try to change it to this approach, anyway it means it's not saved model fault.

What should I change? What is the reason? I'm using Keras everywhere in the project, not *tf.keras* or anything else. *tf.keras* was used there once just to check if it somehow will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution there:[Keras github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8538?fbclid=IwAR1q1ahqH-9CgT2RDwUPqz9qXf3LSTw0PnhH2yZKmyA54VYRV8VILO7S9GE)

Now DNNApi init looks like this:

```
from tensorflow import Graph, Session
...

def __init__(self):
    self.graph_student_index = Graph()
    with self.graph_student_index.as_default():
        self.session_student_index = Session()
        with self.session_student_index.as_default():
            self.CNN_student_index_model = model.CNN_student_index_from_model()

    self.graph_answer = Graph()
    with self.graph_answer.as_default():
        self.session_answer = Session()
        with self.session_answer.as_default():
            self.CNN_answer_model = model.CNN_answer_from_model()
```

and example predict:

```
with self.graph_student_index.as_default():
    with self.session_student_index.as_default():
        for img_index_column in get_index_column(img, required_height, required_width):
                value = self.CNN_student_index_model.predict(img_index_column)
```